# Wiko Sunset 2 Android phone ; Bluetooth adapter name changed with length of more than 256 chars, now cannot change it anymore

Tags: android, bluetooth

I made a test of changing the name of the bluetooth adapter of a `Wiko Sunset 2`, with a length of **more than 256 characters**, and now it cannot be changed anymore, and the bluetooth function cannot work properly anymore, and I have the following message in loop in **Android Studio logcat**:

> 02-07 02:45:47.638 20422-20457/com.reuniware.apps.dvxbluetoothscan   D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
>   02-07 02:45:47.738 20422-20457/com.reuniware.apps.dvxbluetoothscan  D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
>   02-07 02:45:47.839 20422-20457/com.reuniware.apps.dvxbluetoothscan   D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled

Even if I programmatically force the closing of the adapter, this message keeps being sent to the logcat output and I cannot use the bluetooth anymore, and the logo of the bluetooth does not show up anymore.

The way I changed the name is the following:

```
    if (bt==null) bt = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    if (ba==null) ba = bt.getAdapter();
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    ba.setName(uuid.toString().split("\\-")[0] + "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
```

Now when I try to change it with a name with a length of 8 characters then it does not work anymore and no exception is thrown, and the bluetooth seems completely out of order, even after restarting the device.

When I try to get the actual name of the device, it only shows the name with a length of 248 characters.

I think there may have been an overflowing of the bluetooth stack... But not sure at all.

Would you know another way to change it or a way of resetting the bluetooth adapter completely, in order to avoid the factory reset (many important data) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally the only solution I had was to force a factory reset of the device and the Bluetooth adapter seems now ok.